# Json object inside array inside json object using kotlin or java

Tags: java, arrays, json, kotlin

I would like to put a json object inside an array, inside another json object using java or kotlin. Something like this:

```json
{
  "strName" : "hello world"
  "arrAddress" : [
    {
      "strAddress" : "52 street",
      "strPincode" : "683543"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have looked into other questions, but I couldn't find suitable answers.

Comment: You need to create a json array let's say addressObjectArray and add addressObject to the addressObjectArray.  Then add addressObjectArray to objSignUp

Comment: I have already done that and the application is crashing

Comment: Can you please share the logs and code.

Comment: Isn't creating equivalent Java model, populating the model and then serializing them far more intuitive and easy? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer if anyone wants to use JSON objects like these:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("strName", "hello world");
        jsonObject.add("arrAddress", new JsonParser().parse(
                "[\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"strAddress\" : \"52 street\"\n," +
                "      \"strPincode\" : \"683543\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]"
        ));
```

Output:

> {"strName":"hello world","arrAddress":[{"strAddress":"52
> street","strPincode":"683543"}]}